# Video on safari in iOS (iPhone only) keeps opening after closing

Tags: ios, iphone, html, safari, html5-video

I've got this little problem here.
I'm using the HTML5 video-tag on a website, and everytime I try to close it, it keeps re-opening.

This only happens on Safari on iOS, specifically on iPhone. There are no problems with other devices on iOS that I know of.

Website: http://boplancom.webhosting.be (in development)
On your iPhone, just tap the video to start playing, and then try to close it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem was solved. It was a javascript issue where I played the video whenever it came into the viewport.